# How to change bootstrap progress bar color from certain %

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

```js
    var elem = document.getElementById("progress-bar");

    var progress = 75;

    elem.style.width = 80 + '%';
    
    
    if (progress > 80) {
      elem.style.background = "red";
    }
```

```css
#myProgress {
    height: 5px;
}




#progress-bar {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

 <div id="myProgress" class="progress">
       <div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
                              aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
       </div>
 </div>
 
 </body>
 
 </html>
```

I'm using a bootstrap progress bar and I was wondering whether it is possible to change the color of this bar when the percentage is higher than some value.

I have an external Javascript file where I can change the properties of the bar progress:

```
if (progress > 80) {
    elem.style.background = 'red'; // THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO CHANGE
}

elem.style.width = progress + '%';
```

The instruction elem.style.background does not change the colour, any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a working snipped demonstrating your problem.

Comment: what sets the progress bars percentage? do you only set it when the page loads? you would need to listen to whatever event or add an event for changes. when this event fires you would target the progress bar and change its class based on its value.

Comment: Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0kfpqauq/ .
Everything seems to work. Please check

Comment: @ZimSystem ok, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/0kfpqauq/.

```
elem = document.getElementById("progress-bar");

var progress = 90;

elem.style.width = 80 + '%';


if (progress > 80) {
  elem.style.background = "red";
}
```

Comment: Is there any way of changing the colour just from the 80% of the bar? I mean, if progress is 80%, from 0 to 80 the colour is green and from 80 to 100 would be red.

Comment: Do you mean
`if (progress > 80) {
  elem.style.background = "red";
} else {
elem.style.background = "green";
}` ?

Comment: No, I mean if you can change the colour just from the 80% point, so the bar would be green from 0 to 80, and red from 80 to 100%.